# Как при помощи JS убрать списки в теге SELECT

Tags: javascript, jquery

вот скрин бд родительского и дочернего списка услуг
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот так я вывожу на сайт весь список категорий и скрин для него

```
<?php                 
function make_tree($from, $id = 0) {
  $to = array();
  foreach($from as $v) {
    if ($v['parent_id'] == $id) {
      $tmp = $v;
      $tmp['child_list'] = make_tree($from, $tmp['id']);
      $to[] = $tmp;
    }
  }
  return $to;
}

$result = mysql_query("SELECT `id`, `parent_id`, `name`,`name_ru` FROM `category`");
$list = array();
while($cat =  mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $list[] = $cat;
}
$cats = make_tree($list);

/* Теперь вывод: */
function show_tree($from, $level = 0) {
  $indent = str_repeat($level); // $indent = str_repeat('&nbsp;', $level);                                        
  foreach($from as $v) {
    if ($v['child_list']) {
      echo "<optgroup label='" . $indent. $v['name_ru'] . "'>'" . $indent. $v['name'] . "'</optgroup>";
      show_tree($v['child_list'], $level + 1);
    } else {
      echo "<option value='" . $v['name'] . "'>" . $indent . $v['name_ru'] . "</option>";
    }
  }
}
echo "<select name='name' id='name' class='name'>";
echo "<option value=''>Выбрать</option>";
show_tree($cats);
echo "</select>";
?><br>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения] [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как можно сделать при помощи JS. Когда человек выбирает категорию услуг, чтобы в списке "Цель:" появилась только строка "услуги", а "даром", "обмен", и "продажа" пропали.

```html
<select name="target" id="target">
  <option value="">Выберите</option>
  <option value="1" id="obmen">Обмен</option>
  <option value="2" id="darom">Даром</option>
  <option value="3" id="uslugi">Услуги</option>
  <option value="0" id="targeting">Продажа</option>
</select>
```

Comment: а причем тут java?

Comment: приведённый код и результат различаются. приведите код с помощью которого вы получили этот список.

Comment: @webDev_ я вот так список вывожу, я даже скрин сделал

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте написать так:

```
$("#target").change(function(){
    var q=$(this).val();
    $("option", this).each(function(){
        if ($(this).val()!=q){
            $(this).remove();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Попробовал, нет не работает(

Comment: И не будет, если jquery не подключен

Comment: @ArchDemon  подключен

Comment: @Евгений, тогда теги в тему надо ставить не javascript а jquery.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php                 
function make_tree($from, $id = 0)
{
$to = array();
foreach($from as $v)
{
if ($v['parent_id'] == $id)
{
$tmp = $v;
$tmp['child_list'] = make_tree($from, $tmp['id']);
$to[] = $tmp;
}
}
return $to;
}
$result = mysql_query("SELECT `id`, `parent_id`, `name`,`name_ru` FROM `category`");
$list = array();
while($cat =  mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
$list[] = $cat;
}
$cats = make_tree($list);
/* Теперь вывод: */
function show_tree($from, $level = 0) 
{
$indent = str_repeat($level);
// $indent = str_repeat('&nbsp;', $level);                                        foreach($from as $v)
{
if ($v['child_list'])
{
echo "<optgroup label='" . $indent. $v['name_ru'] . "'>'" . $indent. $v['name'] . "'</optgroup>";
show_tree($v['child_list'], $level + 1);
}
else
{
echo $v['name']=='services'?"<option value='" . $v['name'] . "'>" . $indent . $v['name_ru'] . "</option>":"";
}
}
}
echo "<select name='name' id='name' class='name'>";
echo "<option value=''>Выбрать</option>";
show_tree($cats);
echo "</select>";
?>
```

Comment: список пропадает совсем:(

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = document.getElementById("target");
for (var i = 0; i < a.children.length; i++) {
  if (a.children[i].id != "uslugi") {
    a.children[i].style.display = "none";
  } else {
    a.children[i].selected = "selected"
  }
}
```

Comment: Ваш код для всех списков показывает услуги:(

Comment: @Евгений, *Чтобы в списке Цель появилась строка только услуги, а даром и обмен с продажей пропали.* - это же ваши слова. Что не так?

Comment: я изменил немного чтобы яснее стало